# send invitation to sharepoint calendar 2010 via custom web part

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

i'm currently doing a scheduler custom web part that is supposed to:
1) check the availability of a person via his personal sharepoint calendar and a room booking calendar
2) send a meeting request via the custom web part to the **person** after selecting 1 common timeslot FROM the consolidated list of free timeslots based on the 2 calendars
3) once the person accepts the meeting request the custom web part will send a trigger to the workflow to book that timeslot selected

i'm currently trying to find a way to do part (2) and(3) as mentioned above. so far i've seen sending meeting requests to outlook via exchange server, is there anyway to just do it via sharepoint alone?

Appreciate the help! thanks!